# How to prevent html buttons from moving back and forth when I adjust a range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I adjust this range slider, the coresponding text to the right which indicates the video Playback rate, changes from a single digit (i.e. 1) to multiple digits (i.e 0.95). Everytime I do so it causes the buttons directly to the right of the text to move back and forth. I’m wondering how to prevent this movement from happening? I’ve tried adding some space, padding, margin, etc. between the text and buttons but I can’t seem to make it stop. I would defenitely like to keep all of the objects on the same line. Is there a way for example to make the default number of digits constant? For example when it’s set to 1, could it be 1.00 instead, and when it’s .8 can it be 0.80 isntead? I’m not sure if that would work since the playbackrate atribute seems to require a specific number of digits.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#videoPlayerBox{ width:550px; background:#000; margin:0px auto;}
div#videoControlsBar{ background: #333; padding:10px; color:#CCC; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#pbr{ width:40%;}
div#PlaybackRateBox{ margin:left; width:28%; text-align:center; border: solid 3px #000; background:#FFF; padding:0px;}
</style>
<script>
var v,p,c;

function myFunction(){document.getElementById("myForm").reset();} 
function setPlaySpeednormal(){ c.innerHTML = 1;v.playbackRate = 1;}
function restartVideo(){v.pause();v.currentTime = 0;v.play();}

window.onload = function() {
 
  v = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  p = document.getElementById("pbr");
  c = document.getElementById("currentPbr");
 
  p.addEventListener('input',function(){
    c.innerHTML = p.value;
    v.playbackRate = p.value;
  },false);

};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="videoPlayerBox">
    <video id="myVideo" width="100%" poster="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qbvpxvtedcs5lq/2016-07-30_Milonga%20Triste_Guillermo%20Garcia_Tango%20Atipico_San%20Francisco.jpg?raw=1" controls>
<source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rjbtmantuow8vw/testvideo_hfd.mp4?raw=1" 
          type='video/mp4'/>
Your browser does not support HTML video.
    </video>
  
  <div id="videoControlsBar">
    
    <form id= "myForm">
        <input id="pbr" type="range" value="1" min="0.5" max="1.2" step="0.05" class="slider">
        <span>Speed <span id="currentPbr">1</span>
        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="myFunction();setPlaySpeednormal();">
        <input type="button" value="Restart" onclick="restartVideo();"> 
    </form>
  </div>  
  
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this `#currentPbr` line to your style block as shown below (the last line).  Adjust the width to your liking

```
<style>
div#videoPlayerBox{ width:550px; background:#000; margin:0px auto;}
div#videoControlsBar{ background: #333; padding:10px; color:#CCC; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#pbr{ width:40%;}
div#PlaybackRateBox{ margin:left; width:28%; text-align:center; border: solid 3px #000; background:#FFF; padding:0px;}
#currentPbr {display: inline-block; min-width: 80px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that might help you:
`parseNum = (num) => (num == 1 || num === 0) ? num + '.00' : (String(num).length == 3 ? num + '0' : num)`

So, now you can call this function before giving value to c.innerHTML. Thus, instead of `c.innerHTML = p.value`, You can do:

```
var v,p,c;

function myFunction(){document.getElementById("myForm").reset();} 
function setPlaySpeednormal(){ c.innerHTML = 1;v.playbackRate = 1;}
function restartVideo(){v.pause();v.currentTime = 0;v.play();}
const parseNum = (num) => (num == 1 || num === 0) ? num + '.00' : (String(num).length == 3 ? num + '0' : num)

window.onload = function() {
 
  v = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  p = document.getElementById("pbr");
  c = document.getElementById("currentPbr");
 
  p.addEventListener('input',function(){
    c.innerHTML = parseNum(p.value);
    v.playbackRate = p.value;
  },false);

};
```

Here's a screenshot of the function in action:
[image]

***PS*** Be sure not to use this function with every number. It just works for the domain of the volume.

Comment: Thank you Jalaj! parseNum looks very interesting! I’m pretty new with JavaScript so I’m a little confused at how to implement the function in my code. The EventListener part you wrote out “ c.innerHTML = parseNum(p.value); ”was very clear but for the function part, could you tell me how I should write that in to my existing code? I tried to search parseNum online but couldn’t find much info about it. Thanks again!

Comment: Its pretty simple to add the function. As I can't put the code here, because of the word limit, I have edited the answer to include the whole code that should be inside the script tag

Comment: Awesome! It’s works great! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just one weird thing that I still can’t figure out. When I hit the “reset” button now the number reverts to “1” instead of “1.00”. The rest of the time it’s fine. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: This is happening because the function `parseNum` (which changes 1 to 1.00 and all that) is called only when the `input` event is fired on the range slider. And, the event does not fires when you `reset` the form in your `myFunction` function. For a quickfix, you can just edit the `myFunction` to `function myFunction(){document.getElementById("myForm").reset();c.innerHTML = '1.00'}`. This works because in  your case everytime the 'reset' button is pressed, the value should be '1.00' so its useless to call the `parseNum` function there.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for explaining! Actually instead of altering the “myFunction” line I just went to the line below and changed it to `function setPlaySpeednormal(){ c.innerHTML = ‘1.00’; v.playbackRate = 1;}` which solved the problem. :-)